# Convert "YYYYWW" into month (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, calculated-columns, ssrs-2012, data-conversion

I am creating a report and would like to retrieve data based on a date field (string) in the format `YYYYWW`. I want to filter the data so I retrieve the current month, previous month, the month before that and older values - using 4 different datasets.

For example:
`201547 = November 2015`

How do I create a calculated member which converts a string into the month name and year? I would like to use this value to filter out the data from the cube. Is there any other way of doing this?

[image: [Here is a screen shot of my report]:][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27ynv.png)

Comment: Be aware that "week" does not map directly to "month" in a consistent way. How are you going to handle weeks that are split over two months e.g. Monday is the 30th June, Tuesday is 1st July - what month are you going to convert that week to? You'll need to establish some business rules for this. You'll also need to know when "week 1" starts - the week numbering may be linked to *financial year*, not calendar year.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response!! I'll let you guys know how it turned out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a calculated field and set it to this expression:

```
=MonthName(Month(DateAdd("ww",CInt(MID("201547",5,LEN("201547")))
,DateSerial(CInt(LEFT("201547",4)),1,1)))) & " " & LEFT("201547",4)
```

Then use that field to filter your report.

Replace the string for the field returning "201547"

```
=MonthName(Month(DateAdd("ww",
CInt(MID(Fields!YearWeek.Value,5,LEN(Fields!YearWeek.Value)))
,DateSerial(CInt(LEFT(Fields!YearWeek.Value,4)),1,1))))
& " " & LEFT(Fields!YearWeek.Value,4)
```

**UPDATE:** MDX script for querying a calulated member with the required format:

I've tested with the following MDX:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[month&year] AS
  'FORMAT(DateAdd("ww",STRTOVALUE(MID("201547",5,LEN("201547"))) ,CDATE(DateSerial(LEFT("201547",4),1,1))),"MMMM") + " " + LEFT("201547",4)'
SELECT { [month&year] } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Your Cube]
```

To use it in your query replace `"201547"` for `[Dimension].[Attribute].MemberValue` that corresponds to your cube structure:

```
WITH  MEMBER [Measures].[month&year] as 
'FORMAT(DateAdd("ww",STRTOVALUE(MID([Dimension].[Attribute].MemberValue,5,LEN([Dimension].[Attribute].MemberValue)))
,CDATE(DateSerial(LEFT([Dimension].[Attribute].MemberValue,4),1,1))),"MMMM") + " " + LEFT([Dimension].[Attribute].MemberValue,4)'
SELECT
   { [Dimension].[Attribute].[Attribute] }
   {[month&year]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Your Cube]
```

Once you have this field in your dataset you can easily filter the values using a parameter.

Let me know if this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of the resources found out on the internet you can find the information you require.

First you need to find the first day of the first week of the year.  This has already been determined by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532157/2311633) as

```
DateAdd("d", 
    (-1) * (CInt(New DateTime(Year(Now), 1, 1).DayOfWeek) + 
    IIf(CInt(New DateTime(Year(Now), 1, 1).DayOfWeek) < DayOfWeek.Monday, 
        7, 
        0)
    ) + 1, 
    New DateTime(Year(Now), 1, 1))
```

This needs to be adapted for any year - not just the current one by finding the year from the string as follows

```
CInt(Left(Parameters!myDate.Value,4))
```

Now, as noted in [this resource](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4966537a-8725-484e-bfd6-0681d3ed0119/getting-the-date-from-week-number) you can use a `DateAdd` to add the number of weeks of the year you have entered to the first date of the year

```
=(DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,
    CInt(Right(Parameters!myDate.Value,2))-1,
    <<FIRST_DAY_OF_YEAR>>)
```

You then want to get the month name of the month of this date, using `Month` and `MonthName`.  Smashing it all together would result in the following

```
=MonthName(Month(DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,
    CInt(Right(Parameters!myDate.Value,2))-1,
    DateAdd("d", 
        (-1) * (CInt(New DateTime(CInt(Left(Parameters!myDate.Value,4)), 1, 1).DayOfWeek) + 
        IIf(CInt(New DateTime(CInt(Left(Parameters!myDate.Value,4)), 1, 1).DayOfWeek) < DayOfWeek.Monday, 
            7, 
            0)
        ) + 1, 
        New DateTime(CInt(Left(Parameters!myDate.Value,4)), 1, 1))      
    )))
```

This will get a Textual value of the month for the interval

Create a new placeholder in the same textbox and then repeat the above for finding the year

```
=Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, ...
```

*(Remember to remove the last brace otherwise you’ll get a End of Statement expected error.)*

This shoud give what you require, so

```
201501 = December 2014
201547 = November 2015
201553 = December 2015
201622 = May 2016
```

Let me know if this helps, or if you have further questions

Comment: This solution also works great! I would definitely use this as an alternative to the MDX option above.

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1: Establishing which day falls into which week**
ISO-8601 declares the international standards for converting dates into week numbers, and vice-versa.

ISO standard weeks start on a Monday. A year can have either 52 or 53 weeks.

There are 4 ways of establishing when Week 1 starts:
- It is the first week with a majority (4 or more) of its days in January.
- Its first day is the Monday nearest to 1 January.
- It has 4 January in it. Hence the earliest possible dates are 29 December through 4 January, the latest 4 through 10 January.
- It has the year's first working day in it - i.e. excluding Saturdays, Sundays and the 1st of January.

**Part 2: Excel calculations**

This answer assumes that the dates are being stored as 6-character strings.

First determine the year and what day of the week it starts on.

```
1) Strip the first four characters from the string.`  
    =left(<cell containing the year+week string>, 4)
2) Prepend "1/1/" to it.
    ="1/1/"&left(<cell containing the year+week string>, 4)
3) Convert this string to an Excel date    
    =datevalue(<the last result>)
4) Determine the Weekday of the 1st day of that year.  
    =weekday(<the last result>)
5) Calculate the Excel date of the first Monday.
    =if((<the last result>-4)<0,<the result of step 3>+8-<the last result>, <the result of step 3>+1-<the last result>)
6) Work out how many weeks on from that we are:
    =right(<original 6 char year/week string>,2)
7) Convert 6) to a number
    =value(<last result>)
8) Add that to the Monday of Week 1   
    =<result of step 5>+<result of step 7>*7
9) Convert this to a month number
    =month(<last result>)
10) Convert this to a month name
    =choose(<last result>,"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
11) Add the year back on
    =<lastresult>&" "&<result of 1>
```

This gives the month number which contains the Monday of the current numbered week.

If  cell A1 contains '201547
then cell B1 should contain:
`=CHOOSE(MONTH(IF((WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("1/1/"&LEFT(A1,4)))-4)<0,DATEVALUE("1/1/"&LEFT(A1,4))+1-WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("1/1/"&LEFT(A1,4))),DATEVALUE("1/1/"&LEFT(A1,4))+8-WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("1/1/"&LEFT(A1,4))))+7*(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2)))),"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")&" "&LEFT(A1,4)`

If A1 contains 201547 then B1 returns "November 2015".

**Further considerations:**
You may want to make it more sophisicated, so that a month ending in a Monday does not have the week commencing with its final Monday counted as part of the month.  More generally, that week only counts as part of a month is 3 or more of the days are in the month.  Or 3 or more of its working days are part of the month.

As it is, I would  sort with the calculated month and year as primary key and the YYYYMM code as secondary key.

Comment: Is this for determining the result in Excel?  The OP states that they are using Reporting Services...